# Is Bhagavad Gita 9.26 advocating vegetarianism?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/9/verse/26

> पत्रं पुष्पं फलं तोयं यो मे भक्त्या प्रयच्छति |
> तदहं भक्त्युपहृतमश्नामि प्रयतात्मन: || 26||

> patraṁ puṣhpaṁ phalaṁ toyaṁ yo me bhaktyā prayachchhati
> tadahaṁ bhaktyupahṛitam aśhnāmi prayatātmanaḥ

> BG 9.26: If one offers to Me with devotion a leaf, a flower, a fruit, or even water, I delightfully partake of that item offered with love by My devotee in pure consciousness.

Comment: Patram , Pushpam, Palam, Thoyam is only a upalakakshana(not  literal)  .So here the purport does not revel around vegetarianism , rather it conveys  , devotional quotient is all that matters.So one would  not in the least, worry about the quantum of offering, (like one tenth of one's earnings etc.).Dharmashastra is an appropriate shastra one can refer to, for any concerns on vegetarianism.

Comment: @Athrey - regardless, the delineation of food into Sattva, Rajas and Tamas - indicates that vegetarian food is (mostly) satvik. While this particular shloka does not dictate vegetarianism, BG as a whole, does. Anyway, there is no agama other than Shakta which mandates non-vegetarian neivedya for deity.

Comment: @mar ,  Vegetarianism is less relatable here, as this question is restricted to 9.26
True that Gita does designate the nature of satv,. rajas & tamas food,( as it impacts gunas)Also It can't be denied, that (mostly) vegetarian bears the lakshana of what is sattvic, Yet neivedya is the subject matter of agama shastra /(vegetarianism : dharmashastra).Any comprehensive delineation, can only be gotten only from respective shastras, the topic being it's subject matter.So It is said in Gita 16.24 **tasmat shastram pramanam te karya akarya vyavasthitau**

Comment: As all animal sacrifices are eschewed in Kali yuga by shaastras ,non vegetarian is amedha thus it falls under tamasic class.Even otherwise it's very nature is not satvik. Interms of ahimsa, dukha is more for animals when they are slain, so In a way it's true that BG seems to support vegetarianism,

Comment: You are trying to extrapolate a meaning, asking for opinions